# "Parameters dictionary contains null for parameter of non-nullable type"?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a null error for id when I run. Here are all my parts.

Here is my DAL, ProjectDB

```
 public static List<Product> IsOrganic(int lotid)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductDB())
        {   //Selects from database in SQL what we need
            //IsDamaged is Organic, and bool for true/false for food
            DbCommand cmd = db.GetSqlStringCommand("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ORGANIC = 1");


            return FillList(db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd));
        }
    }
```

Here is my Manager

```
public List<Product> IsOrganic(int lotid)
    {


        return ProductDB.IsOrganic(lotid);


    }
```

Here is my Controller

```
 public ActionResult Organic(int id)//Store/Organic
    {
        ProductManager mgr = new ProductManager();

        var list = mgr.IsOrganic(id);

        return View(list);
    }
```

Also, here is my Global

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Yyou will get that error if you fail to pass in the parameter.

Comment: The error describes exactly what the problem is. What does your request and route setup look like?

Comment: That error occurs at a higher level, when the framework tries to call your controller method. The execution does not reach the code you showed.

Comment: a: your route presumably isn't passing `id` into the action, and b: you aren't using `id` in the method, so why does it exist?

Comment: Would the route information be in my Global file asawyer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C# 4, use default value for optional parameter

```
public ActionResult Organic(int id = 0)//Store/Organic
{
    ProductManager mgr = new ProductManager();

    var list = mgr.IsOrganic(id);

    return View(list);
}
```

If C# 3 only, use DefaultValue attribute for optional parameter

```
public ActionResult Organic(
      [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(0)] int id) //Store/Organic
{
    ProductManager mgr = new ProductManager();

    var list = mgr.IsOrganic(id);

    return View(list);
}
```

But I'm wondering why you are calling Organic method that way, that is with no parameter.

If you want to test if the StoreController's Organic action is working, type this in url:

http://localhost/Store/Organic/7

or this:

http://localhost/Store/Organic?id=7

If you used custom name for the parameter id of your StoreController's Organic action, say organicId:

```
public ActionResult Organic(int organicId = 0) //Store/Organic?organicId=7
{
    ProductManager mgr = new ProductManager();

    var list = mgr.IsOrganic(id);

    return View(list);
}
```

,this url will not work: http://localhost/Store/Organic/7

,that will not have runtime error, but the organicId value won't be passed a value, and as such will always have a value of 0

,you must use this instead: http://localhost/Store/Organic?organicId=7

By the way, where does the runtime error come from? Upon clicking a link? Try to hover on that link and look at your browser's status bar, yourl URL must conform to this:  http://localhost/Store/Organic/7 or this http://localhost/Store/Organic?id=7.

If it doesn't look that way, change your ActionLink to this:

`@Html.ActionLink("Store", "Organic", new {id = 7})`

or if you are using plain HTML:

```
<a href="Store/Organic/7">
```

Or this:

```
<a href="Store/Organic?id=7">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did some thing and I may have fixed that id error. I am now getting this error when I run it, doing /store/organic   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\MYNAE.UNI\Dropbox\WebDev2\Project (Final)\NewProj3\NewProj3\App_Data\StoreDB.sdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.                                                                    This is in my AbstractDatabase.cs

Comment: But the database file is in that location, I doubled checked =\

Comment: "Thanks for the reply. I did some thing and I **may** have fixed that id error." ツ Shouldn't the problem be [reproducible](http://blog.sobbayi.com/a-run-down-of-the-best-computer-programmer-jokes/), so one shall know how to fix it again when he/she encounter the same kind of error? You can post your db problem on separate question, it also may have a higher chance of being solved in http://serverfault.com/ or http://dba.stackexchange.com/ both sister sites of http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: Calling it that way without a parameter is what a user might do, at least that's why I want a custom error page for that case. Can I check for that error in the Execute method (if id == null .. some error handling) or is the program stopped as soon the function is called with a wrong/missing parameter?